# Mysql not working, After uninstall Mariadb in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have PHP and Mysql was already running on Ubuntu VERSION 20.04

Today, I have tried to install the Maria db, but it wasn't working, So i have removed the mariadb using below command

```
apt-get purge mariadb-server mariadb-*
```

Now mysql is not working anymore, when i ran

```
sudo service mysql status
```

It gives me error,

> Unit mysql.service could not be found.

I have tried following things but none of them work, it is giving same error.

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo systemctl stop mysqld
sudo systemctl stop mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a common issue when people uninstall MariaDB. Generally the best option is to wipe MySQL completely, then reinstall it. Here are the steps:

```
sudo apt remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt purge mysql*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt remove dbconfig-mysql
```

It would probably also be a good idea to ensure the data directory is gone.

1. check if `/var/lib/mysql` exists, if so, do (2)
2. `sudo rm -Rf /var/lib/mysql`

From there you can re-install MySQL:

1. `sudo apt install mysql-server`
2. `sudo mysql_secure_installation`
3. (optional) restore databases & user accounts

Hope this helps you.